# derivative of integral with exponential term

Tags: integration, derivatives

Is this correct?  $\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\gamma t}(X^{\rm T}(t)C^{\rm T}QCX(t)+u^{\rm T}(t)Ru(t)){\rm d}t=e^{-\gamma t}(X^{\rm T}(t)C^{\rm T}QCX(t)+u^{\rm T}(t)Ru(t))$. or am I missing some terms? Please note that $Q$, $C$ and $R$ are constant matrices of appropriate dimensions, $\gamma>0$ a positive constant. $C^{\rm T}$ denote transpose of matrix $C$.

Thank you

Comment: I find the equation somewhat confusing. I take that $Q$, $R$, $C$, $T$ are constants while $X$ and $u$ are functions?

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention that all the variables are matrices and..T is an operator, denotes transpose of matrix.

Comment: You are intergrating a function of $t$ with respect to $t$, hence the value of the intergral does not depend on $t$. Then you derive this result with respect to $t$, hence the anser is $0$.

Comment: @Tzakreskiy Thank you for your comment, oh, you are right, once I integrate and apply limits then the result of integration is a constant value and does not involve variable t, thus differentiating a constant gives zero.  So question is wrong, this is actually a part of another derivation. Thank you for quick answer.